# Advantage of Javascript object prototyping?

Tags: javascript

I recently started learning about prototypes in Javascript.  I am confused about the advantage of adding methods into a prototype.  Here is an example of what I am thinking

One way to calculate the area of a circle could be like this

```
function Circle(radius, area){
  this.radius = radius;
  this.area = (radius*radius*Math.PI);
}
```

But then another way would be like this

```
function Circle(radius, area){
  this.radius = radius;
}

Circle.prototype.area = function(){
  return this.radius*this.radius*Math.PI
}
```

What is the advantage to making the area method a part of the prototype versus putting a method directly in the constructor?

Comment: You  haven't put a method in the constructor. If you had, the advantage would be that the prototype method is available for all instances rather than creating a new method for each instance.

Comment: what if you wanna add a method to a native function that you don't have access to the constructor..

Comment: That's just a bad example (with some confusing implementation / arguments), but basically, think of strings... do you "like" having prototype methods on strings? that's the "advantage".

Comment: if the method is defined as a prototype method then whenever you will create a new object from that constructor function then all the objects will have a single prototype method and changing  anything in this prototype method will reflect changes for all the object but if the method is not defined as a prototype method then all the objects will contain this method so it will be duplication of code

Answer (score 0):

> What is the advantage to making the area method a part of the prototype versus putting a method directly in the constructor?

You don't put a method in the constructor, but instead the already calculated area-value. The area-method has the following advantages:

- The current value is calculated even if the radius was changed.
- The area can't be changed to a wrong value by foreign code.
- You can change the unit that is used internally without affecting code that uses the object.
- It (hopefully) needs less memory which might be useful if you have a huge amount of these objects.